# opshub migration utility - one step has been running ~9 hours - is it possibly jacked up?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

My client has ~10 team projects in TFS 2013 that we are currently migrating to VSTS.  During this last week, 9 of those 10 team projects (which are fairly small/medium in size/changeset numbers) migrated in a totally reasonable amount of time.   However, the last (and most important) team project is large, and it appears to be stuck during migration.  It has been stuck at migrating step 405/700 for us for ~9 hours now.

I am mainly concerned because the migration was churning along decently yesterday up until I left work for the night yesterday, but I had a (unrelated) computer crash overnight, and so I don't know if that has had an impact on the migration.  Because of the computer crash I had to restart the migration this morning, and it seemed to pick up where it left off, but it has not budged (according to the UI) all day.  The last changeset I see checked in to our VSTS was at 8:18pm last night, which means nothing has made it over to VSTS for almost 20 hours.

Upon looking at the logs, SOMETHING seems to be happening - it is still writing data to the logs. I'm just hoping that someone can tell me to have patience because it is still working (just slowly), or if it is truly stuck and I should start over and/or have a plan B.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data it keeps writing? Can you share the logs?

Answer (score 0):

The case has been resolved. The tool was running out-of-memory while processing a large changeset, since default allocation of memory to JVM was just 1 GB. Providing more memory did the trick and the migration completed.

Steps to increase the allocation.

1) Close application

2) Go to \OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\OpsHubServer6.0.16\bin (Installation Drive may be: C:\Program Files)(Folder name might be OpsHubServer6.0.16 or just OpsHubServer depending on your version)

3) Open service.bat in NotePad. Find following string "-Xmx1024m". Replace -Xmx2048m to -Xmx4096m (or the appropriate number for the max memory size, if you have more available)

4) Save file

5) In same folder

Run **unregisterservice.bat** as administrator (Which will unregister OpsHub service. Verify by opening services.msc there will be no "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" service any more)

Run **registerservice.bat** as administrator (Which will register OpsHub service. Verify by opening services.msc and there will be "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" service with "Automatic" startup type)

6) Open services.msc, Right click on "**OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility**" , Click on properties, select startup type "Manual" click on "Apply"

7) Start application which will now use 4096m memory (4 GB) or whatever amount specified in step 3